# trying to calculate BMI but get a 0.0 answer after using Math.round()

Tags: java

So I'm trying to calculate my bmi using the following method.

```
double bmi = weight / ((height * 100) * (height * 100));
bmi = Math.round(bmi * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

From the first line I get an answer that looks like this:

2.3457310760477412E-7

which is why I want to round this to one or two decimals. But this results in bmi being 0.0 instead.

I have also tried decimalformat which also returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - SOLUTION

The problem was my formula! Centimeter should be divided by 10 not multiplied!
Thanks!

//André

Comment: 2.3457310760477412E-7 rounded to 2 decimal points is 0.00. 2.3457310760477412E-7 without scientific notation is 0.00000023457...

Comment: Thanks Mr Goat, that made me find the problem.
Should be double bmi = weight / ((height / 100) * (height / 100)); 
It was just my formula!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you are getting from your first line, `2.3457310760477412E-7` is already kinda small. It is roughly equal to `2.345/10000000` or `0.00000023457`. And this is very close to zero. `Math` works as expected, rounding the number to the closest integer - `0`.

The error is either in the input variables or in the fomula you are using. Maybe you have your height given in centimeters instead of meters?

Answer (score 0):

```
double weight = 89.0;
double height = 169.0;
double bmi = (weight / ((height * height) / 100)) * 100;
```

To clarify, weight and height are metric (KG/CM) - you need to convert the height in CM to meters (so you divide by 100) then the output is multiplied by 100 to give the BMI.